# What are the available choices for tkinter.PanedWindow's sashcursor?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I can't find comprehensive widget documentation of Tkinter.

According to [this tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm), PanedWindow has a `sashcursor` option, but the available options are not provided.

I looked it over in [TK's docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/panedwindow.htm#M13), only to find that these TK options such as `sb_h_double_arrow`  can't be directly used with Tkinter.

Comment: It's a mystery. Even `import tkinter as tk; help(tk.PanedWindow)` is silent on what the options are. I suppose they're hiding in `tk.constants`.

Comment: Isn't it just all [cursors](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html)?

Comment: @fhdrsdg Unfortunately no, among your cursors, sb_h_double_arrow was the one I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any valid cursor name supported by your system.

For example:

```
pw = tk.PanedWindow(sashcursor="gumby")
```

In your question you claim that `sb_h_double_arrow` can't be used, but that's not true. For example, this should work unless your system doesn't have the cursor installed for some reason:

```
pw = tk.PanedWindow(sashcursor="sb_h_double_arrow")
```

The definitive list of supported cursors can be found in the tcl/tk documentation, which can be found here: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm

A version of the documentation which includes images for each cursor can be found here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html